# NLTK. Lesk returns different result for the same input

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, wordnet, disambiguation

I'm using LESK algorithm for getting SynSets from the text. But I'm getting different results with the same inputs. 
Is it Lesk algorithm "feature" or am I doing something wrong?
Next is the code I'm using:

```
    self.SynSets =[]
    sentences = sent_tokenize("Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.\
        Its design philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C++ or Java.\
        The language provides constructs intended to enable clear programs on both a small and large scale.\
        Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming or procedural styles.\
        ")
    stopwordsList =  stopwords.words('english')
    self.sentNum=0;
    for sentence in sentences:
        raw_tokens =  word_tokenize(sentence)
        final_tokens = [token.lower() for token in raw_tokens 
                    if(not token in stopwordsList) 
                    #and (len(token) > 3) 
                    and not token.isdigit()]
        for token in final_tokens:
            synset = wsd.lesk(sentence, token)
            if not synset is None:
                self.SynSets.append(synset)

    self.SynSets = set(self.SynSets)
    self.WriteSynSets()
    return self
```

At the output I'm having results (first 3 results from 2 different launching):

```
Synset('allow.v.09')   Synset('code.n.03')   Synset('coffee.n.01') 
------------
Synset('allow.v.09')   Synset('argumentation.n.02')   Synset('boastfully.r.01')
```

If there is some another (more stable) way to get synsets, I will be thankfull for yours help.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edited

For additional example here is full script that I've ran for 2 times:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import wsd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

SynSets =[]
sentences = sent_tokenize("Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.\
    Its design philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C++ or Java.\
    The language provides constructs intended to enable clear programs on both a small and large scale.\
    Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming or procedural styles.\
    ")
stopwordsList =  stopwords.words('english')

for sentence in sentences:
    raw_tokens =  word_tokenize(sentence)#WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(sentence)
    #removing stopwords and words, smaller than 3 characters
    final_tokens = [token.lower() for token in raw_tokens 
                if(not token in stopwordsList) 
                #and (len(token) > 3) 
                and not token.isdigit()]
    for token in final_tokens:
        synset = wsd.lesk(sentence, token)
        if not synset is None:
            SynSets.append(synset)


SynSets = set(SynSets)

SynSets = sorted(SynSets)
with open("synsets.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write("\n-------------------\n")
    for synset in SynSets:
        file.write("{}   ".format(str(synset.__str__())))
file.close()
```

and I had these results (first 4 resulted synsets that was written in the file for each of 2 times tat i ran program):

- Synset('allow.v.04')   Synset('boastfully.r.01') Synset('clear.v.11') Synset('code.n.02')
- Synset('boastfully.r.01')   Synset('clear.v.19')   Synset('code.n.01')   Synset('design.n.04')

**SOLUTION:
I've got what was the problem. After re-installing python 2.7 all problems has gone.
So, don't use python 3.x with lesk algorithm.**

Answer (score 2):

There is a wsd function for lesk algorithm in the latest version of NLTK:

```
>>> from nltk.wsd import lesk
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize
>>> text = "Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language. Its design philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C++ or Java. The language provides constructs intended to enable clear programs on both a small and large scale. Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming or procedural styles."
>>> for sent in sent_tokenize(text):
...     for word in word_tokenize(sent):
...             print word, lesk(sent, word), sent
```

[out]:

```
Python Synset('python.n.02') Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.
is Synset('be.v.08') Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.
a Synset('angstrom.n.01') Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.
widely Synset('wide.r.04') Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.
used Synset('use.v.01') Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.
general-purpose None Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.
, None Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.
```

---

Also, try the `disambiguate()` from `pywsd` (https://github.com/alvations/pywsd):

```
>>> from pywsd import disambiguate>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize
>>> text = "Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language. Its design philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C++ or Java. The language provides constructs intended to enable clear programs on both a small and large scale. Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming or procedural styles."
>>> for sent in sent_tokenize(text):
...     print disambiguate(sent, prefersNone=True)
...
```

[out]:

```
[('Python', Synset('python.n.02')), ('is', None), ('a', None), ('widely', Synset('widely.r.03')), ('used', Synset('used.a.01')), ('general-purpose', None), (',', None), ('high-level', None), ('programming', Synset('scheduling.n.01')), ('language', Synset('terminology.n.01')), ('.', None)]
[('Its', None), ('design', Synset('purpose.n.01')), ('philosophy', Synset('philosophy.n.03')), ('emphasizes', Synset('stress.v.01')), ('code', Synset('code.n.03')), ('readability', Synset('readability.n.01')), (',', None), ('and', None), ('its', None), ('syntax', Synset('syntax.n.03')), ('allows', Synset('let.v.01')), ('programmers', Synset('programmer.n.01')), ('to', None), ('express', Synset('express.n.03')), ('concepts', Synset('concept.n.01')), ('in', None), ('fewer', None), ('lines', Synset('wrinkle.n.01')), ('of', None), ('code', Synset('code.n.03')), ('than', None), ('would', None), ('be', None), ('possible', Synset('potential.a.01')), ('in', None), ('languages', Synset('linguistic_process.n.02')), ('such', None), ('as', None), ('C++', None), ('or', None), ('Java', Synset('java.n.03')), ('.', None)]
[('The', None), ('language', Synset('language.n.01')), ('provides', Synset('provide.v.06')), ('constructs', Synset('concept.n.01')), ('intended', Synset('mean.v.03')), ('to', None), ('enable', None), ('clear', Synset('open.n.01')), ('programs', Synset('program.n.08')), ('on', None), ('both', None), ('a', None), ('small', Synset('small.a.01')), ('and', None), ('large', Synset('large.a.01')), ('scale', Synset('scale.n.10')), ('.', None)]
[('Python', Synset('python.n.02')), ('supports', Synset('support.n.11')), ('multiple', None), ('programming', Synset('program.v.02')), ('paradigms', Synset('substitution_class.n.01')), (',', None), ('including', Synset('include.v.03')), ('object-oriented', None), (',', None), ('imperative', Synset('imperative.a.02')), ('and', None), ('functional', Synset('functional.a.01')), ('programming', Synset('scheduling.n.01')), ('or', None), ('procedural', Synset('procedural.a.01')), ('styles', Synset('vogue.n.01')), ('.', None)]
```

They're not perfect but they are close to the accurate implementation of lesk.

---

**EDITED**

To verify that it's the same results everytime you run, there should be no STDOUT when you do this:

```
from nltk.wsd import lesk
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
text = "Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language. Its design philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C++ or Java. The language provides constructs intended to enable clear programs on both a small and large scale. Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming or procedural styles."

lst = []
for sent in sent_tokenize(text):
    lst = []
    for word in word_tokenize(sent):
        lst.append(lesk(sent, word))
    for i in range(10):
        lst2 = []
        for word in word_tokenize(sent):
            lst2.append(lesk(sent, word))
        assert lst2 == lst
```

I ran the OP's code 10 times but it yields the same result:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import wsd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def run():
    SynSets =[]
    sentences = sent_tokenize("Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming language.\
        Its design philosophy emphasizes code readability, and its syntax allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than would be possible in languages such as C++ or Java.\
        The language provides constructs intended to enable clear programs on both a small and large scale.\
        Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming or procedural styles.\
        ")
    stopwordsList =  stopwords.words('english')

    for sentence in sentences:
        raw_tokens =  word_tokenize(sentence)#WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(sentence)
        #removing stopwords and words, smaller than 3 characters
        final_tokens = [token.lower() for token in raw_tokens 
                    if(not token in stopwordsList) 
                    #and (len(token) > 3) 
                    and not token.isdigit()]
        for token in final_tokens:
            synset = wsd.lesk(sentence, token)
            if not synset is None:
                SynSets.append(synset)
    return sorted(set(SynSets))

run1 = run()

for i in range(10):
    assert run1 == run()
```

Comment: I have NLTK 3.0.1 installed.
And I'm using wsd.lesk from NLTK. 
Probem is different result in output. Did you have similar issue?
For pywsd - thanks. I'll try it

Comment: Are you calling it correctly? There's no different when i run it 10 times. How did you call lesk from NLTK?

Comment: I have  difference when i relaunch the program.
You can see  how i'm usin lesk from example.

Comment: It's not that different, using your code, i ran your code 10 times and it's still the same.

Comment: I Ran your code as well. It finished without any exceptions. But then i ran my code(relaunching. with finishing program to the end) and ir did have different results. What is wrong with this?(

Comment: i ran your code without changing anything and i got this output: http://pastebin.com/PurJLhCH . There's still no difference, is there any other part of your code changing the synsets list?

Comment: If all else fails, try the pywsd disambiguate module. I'm quite sure it's stable after several round of testing and also the author of the module is the same nltk.wsd.lesk ;)

Comment: Thanks for responce. I've tried to run my code from the different machine. As same issue - different results.
Tried to install pywsd (downloaded from github and copied pywsd folder into the c:/python34. Than - when trying to import - lesk module not found error occures)
Also i've tried to run code with nltk.lesk - just for the 1 sentence - having diffrent result.

Comment: Also I've tried to update nltk and python - didn't help.
I'm running my code from VS 2013.
Also I've uploaded all my code here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8AKmvfIdZnRREE3U21PeDlveW8&usp=sharing  (code in SynSetTable file).
Thanks

Comment: I gona reinstall Windows if it help)
I just cannot understand why is so determinic code behaves in so unpredictible way.

Comment: what version nltk/python are you using?

Comment: sorry i went for a long holiday for cny. I was using the nltk v3.0. But i guess @dimazest should have it fixed.